# unable to configure cloudflare flexible ssl on joomla 3.x website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, joomla, cloudflare

I'm having some annoying problems with my domain http://www.armfilmbihar.com..

I have **Cloudflare flexible SSL on my joomla 3.3 site,** and it makes a https call, IF I type it myself >< When I try to force https to be used on my site via a **htaccess file I get a loop error**.
On using the page rules from cf website, it is loading but it is **showing parts as insecure content** and thus blocking. *How do I change all of them to https so that content loads with ssl?*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the information in our knowledge base about [mixed content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170476-How-do-I-fix-the-SSL-Mixed-Content-Error-Message-)?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried the above. But the problem is with joomla configuration, because upon using full ssl in admin panel, there occurs a redirection loop. I dont know how to solve it..

Comment: Is the admin panel already forcing https://? Does this issue go away if you use Flexible and not full?

Comment: let me clarify something, i cannot use full ssl in cf(using flexible ssl) because i dont have ssl cert (as well as business plan). Now on applying full ssl option in joomla configuration in admin panel, i get the redirection loop as stated above..pls help.

Comment: Hi,

I'm going to have to ask you to open a support ticket at this point. We really need to look at the account to see your configuration, then work from there to figure out why it is causing an issue with Flexible.